# Is it possible to safely/securely check in API keys etc. into a repository?

Tags: node.js, git

I load sensitive details (eg, AWS Secret) into my `node` project with [`dotenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) & an `.env` file, which I include in my `.gitignore`, as I've read that's best practice.

If I want to add others to the project, or even clone the repo on another system, what's the most efficient/safe way to transmit these sensitive details? I assume email/google drive are out, but I'm not sure what's 'in.'

My repo is private--does that mean the 'don't check-in API keys' advice is less concrete? As I see it, anyone with permission to see the repo will likely need relevant API keys, so it doesn't seem too unreasonable to simply check them in.

Comment: Use an encrypted communications channel. Depending on who you trust that could be Skype, Slack, Whatsapp, encrypted jabber, PGP encrypted email, encrypted zip file in a normal email (the password sent via skype, whatsapp etc.) or, I've seen it done by a previous employer, an encrypted zip file in a private git repo

Comment: [cheap-secrets](https://github.com/bpo/cheap-secrets) is an example of how to pgp encrypt a file with a number of developers public keys so any of those private keys can decrypt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is always a trade-off with convenience. There are no real absolutes. Are you cool with anyone who accesses the repository and the (potential) git host having access to the keys? Are all developers' computer secure and use disk encryption? What do the keys give access to? Everything on AWS? Do you trust people with access to the repo enough to stay secure and not accidentally share things further? The point is that you need to try to fully understand in which ways the secrets may be leaked.

Personally I rather keep them outside of git and distribute keys to developers via usb sticks or encrypted email. And only to the people who need them. Only a subset of our developers actually need access.

Just make sure that you replace all your secrets if you do decide it's too risky. Don't just delete them from the repository. Once they are in there, they are in there forever.